# PHP encrypt return with HTML keygen public key

Tags: php, html, encryption, key, generator

How can I encrypt - anything - within PHP with the public key I get from HTML5's keygen? Is there a standard function for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501196/keygen-tag-in-html5) includes some lengthy documentation on `<keygen />` but for me the biggest take-away would definitely be that this tag is not supported in IE (any version); if you can get away with ignoring IE, then that post should help.

Comment: Like others have mentioned, there is no support for IE with keygen yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer selected is absolutely incorrect!

If you are using the *keygen* element to generate a symmetric encryption key, it will negate any protections offered by using encryption in the first place.

Sending a symmetric encryption key over an insecure channel is one the first rules of using cryptography. Private keys are just that, private. What's more a public key should not be used as an encryption password, it can be used to encrypt data and/or verify data if it is an RSA keytype.

The *keygen* element should be used to generate a *signed public key & challenge* by first creating a private key (RSA) which gets registered and used by the browser to provide *[certificate based authentication](http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html)*.

For further research confirming this answer please see the following references:

1. [KeyGen w/ PHP](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/attachments/20080714/07ea5534/attachment.txt)
2. [OpenSSL SPKAC documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/spkac.html)
3. [Certificate Signing Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request)
4. [PHP OpenSSL SPKAC patch (available within the latest master branch)](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=8f56ac8401ed1c3e00b8fba3fb8e5efb565180c4)
5. [Standalone patch for PHP OpenSSL extension for working natively with SPKAC's sent from the browsers KenGen element](https://github.com/jas-/SPKAC-PHP-OpenSSL)
6. [PHP documentation for SPKI](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-spki-new.php)

Answer (score 0):

generates signed public keys, also known as SPKACs. The only easy way I know of to use them is to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SPKAC implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->loadSPKAC('MIIBQzCBrTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAwnnEID0RuUfmVbB1rNgsZ6BL8MtITio00wLJhQ075cvxcgllis1M4PhK6SKtm0tmSfXZTZz8jrbeczSFkdl6UjFYCXIrxnmcGmpB4A6fdKsBfFtmMOPLXLr5nGM+4DyOMZCZObbLOnsv7usimDpixk+juZ65Gmhb9rB+2MAKEbECAwEAARYJMTIzNDU2Nzg5MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4GBAB99Nkdhzeazy0bTCb69Mp8Q3BDOgeMonUEg0ETlPaTX/y9HvwkgWHdMROQmc8JiDNTZZzpssrgdKtzsqQOyEIOHEKDbAXL3+GlglCaQ3g/72PbJPFusYdsPjEPYKXil6U1nCikikjaEZVM1HbzVFSmbEAuLwYwD1Z6LovYYaxr0');

$pubkey = (string) $x509->getPublicKey();
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($pubkey);
echo bin2hex($rsa->encrypt('whatever'));
```

Comment: this actually is the correct answer. helped me alot. thank you very much :)

Comment: You can now use PHP's OpenSSL extension (native support) now by calling ['openssl_export()'](1) on the SPKAC value sent to the server.

[1]http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-spki-export.php

Answer (score -2):

You can use the mcrypt functions available in PHP (if you have the library extension available on your server) - for example

Your HTML Form has a field: `<keygen name="mykey" />`

Your PHP could do something like: (not tested)

```
$myKey = $_POST['mykey']; // this is your posted keygen value
$encryptThis = 'This is the text I want to encrypt';
$cipher = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher, $mode);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encOutput = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $myKey, $encryptThis, $mode, $iv);

// your encrypted text is now in the variable $encOutput
```

For more on mcrypt see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: keygen generates SPKAC formatted public keys. The first set of bytes are going to be the same and the bytes that aren't the same aren't going to have as much variation as they could possibly have. Using an SPKAC as a key for a symmetric cipher is probably reducing the number of effective bytes of security down from, let's say, 128, to probably 50 or so..

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong answer. To use the value submitted from a &lt;keygen&gt; element is very insecure.

You essentially just sent the password used for encryption over a public channel therefore negating any security you would have gained from symmetric encryption.

A SPKAC (signed public key and challenge) is to be used for certificate authentication, not as a symmetric encryption key.