# Is there a HTML5 keygen example?

Tags: html

I am having difficulty understanding how to use `<keygen>`.

I could not find the demo for it, which is used for authentication. When I add the `<keygen>` tag to the form, it sends the public key.

What should be done after getting the public key?

Can someone please give me sample application which uses `<keygen>` and does the authentication?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501196/keygen-tag-in-html5?

Comment: Yes i have read the above link. My question is to generate the certificate at server and send it back for user authentication. I looking out for complete example which generates the certificate using keygen public key

Comment: Then you would have seen:
This specification does not specify how the private key generated is to be used. It is expected that after receiving the SignedPublicKeyAndChallenge (SPKAC) structure, the server will generate a client certificate and offer it back to the user for download; this certificate, once downloaded and stored in the key store along with the private key, can then be used to authenticate to services that use TLS and certificate authentication.

Comment: Full example with PHP and Apache: http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/attachments/20080714/07ea5534/attachment.txt

Comment: The whatwg list seems to be down, but it's archived: https://archive.is/WnBdK

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen:

_This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mozilla has some working examples here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/keygen

Comment: Please note it has been deprecated and removed in meantime

Answer (score 7):

My explanations come from this PHP/Apache [example](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/attachments/20080714/07ea5534/attachment.txt). It's a simplified explanation, look at the original example for full details.

The client generate a public key for the server and keep a private key.

```
<form>
   <keygen name="pubkey" challenge="randomchars">
   <input type="submit" name="createcert" value="Generate">
</form>
```

The public key is extracted by the server:

```
$key = $_REQUEST['pubkey'];
```

The server build a client certificate:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/openssl ca -config ".$opensslconf." -days ".$days." -notext -batch -spkac ".$certfolder.$uniq.".spkac -out ".$certfolder.$uniq." -passin pass:'".$capw."' 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

and send it back to the client.

You can then configure Apache to allow access to authentified clients:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLCertificateFile /etc/CA/certs-pub/domain.der
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/CA/certs-priv/domain.pem
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/CA/certs-pub/ca.pem
SSLCARevocationFile /etc/CA/crl/cacrl.pem
<Location /secure_area/>
  SSLVerifyClient require
  SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Location>
```

Comment: Note to future readers: You should never execute commands that have unsanitized user input. They could compromise your server