# Stop malicious third parties from seeing info in plain text

Tags: ruby, html, security, sinatra, erb

I am writing a program that requires a log in, in Ruby, also using Sinatra.

I need to encrypt the password in the form before it is sent so a third party user doesn't read/use the plain text. Currently I am using the `<keygen>` HTML 5 tag in the ERB to generate a key to use with ezcrypto.

Here is the code:

```
  <form action="/" method="post">
 password: <input type="password" name="pass">
 Encryption: <keygen name="security" keytype="RSA"> </keygen>
 <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

I was wondering if this would stop those third parties from being able to view the plain text of the key and the password or if I am not solving anything, if so some advice would be nice

Comment: Did you actually try this out? Does the password really get encrypted? Because that's not how `<keygen>` is supposed to work, see the [example form submission at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711299/is-there-a-html5-keygen-example

Comment: I am not actually positive but I was looking at it and it seems that it generates a key (duh key-gen) but I still don't know what to do with that

Comment: Read the article i linked to over at MDN. The tag will *not* encrypt anything, it is merely a way to exchange a key between the client and the server. As far as i can see, the key exchange itself is not secure so an attacker that would be able to read the plain password will be able to read the key and thus will also be able to decrypt a password encrypted with this key.

Comment: You could just use HTTPS to establish a secure connection. Wouldn't that be an option?

Comment: I have never used HTTPS before and was wondering if it would also protect from people seeing the password in plain text also would I need an ssl?

Comment: I am not sure about what problem you want to solve. If you do not want a user to be able to see/read a value and the user is not able to change the value, why to you send the value to the user at all?