# PHP backend / frontend security

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications, security

**Hello all,**

While taking my time in the bath I though of something interesting. In PHP, how do you tell if the users' forms submitted is valid and not fraud (i.e. some other form on some other site with action="http://mysite.com/sendData.php")? Because really, anyone can create a form that will try send and match $_POST variables in the real backend. How can I make sure that ***that*** script is legit (from my site and only my site) so I don't have some sort of cloning-site data-steal thing going on?

I have some ideas but not sure where to start

- Generate a one-time key and store in hidden input field
- Attempt (however possible) to grab the url on which the form is located (probably not possible)
- Using some really complicated PHP goodies to determine where the data is sent (possible)

Any ideas? Thanks all!

Comment: Random one-time keys are the way to go. Don't bother trying to check where the request is coming from, even if there are ways these can be spoofed easily.

Comment: This is well documented, a simple Google search will provide you with plenty of information on the subject. Even if you know where the data is coming from, it is extremely easy to edit the HTML of a page. The best thing is to validate all of your data server-side, it shouldn't really matter where it comes from if you do it correctly.

Comment: lol okay one-time-keys and session hashes everywhere.. but why the -1? XD

Comment: People are hard at work under the pressure of deadlines and you're taking a relaxing bath. DOWNVOTE! :P (it wasn't me!)

Comment: Do you differentiate this as opposed to someone scraping your site for everything and then sending spoofed values from a different source?

Comment: I am an undergrad taking compsci/economics -.- I THINK during baths (because it's efficient), how is that relaxing? I have deadlines too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these attempts from hackers will be used by curl. It's easy to change the referring agent with curl. You can even set cookies with curl. But spoofing md5 hashed keys with a private salt and storing it in session data will stop most average hackers and bots. Keeping the keys stored in a database will add authentication.

Answer (score 0):

There are few simple ways like:

- Checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to ensure your host was the referring script
- Adding hashing keys in the forms and checking them with the server session variable stored.

But all the above can be manipulated and spoofed in some way. So, you can use **CSRF Validations**. Here is a very good [article](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries) on this.

Other additional techniques I have encountered are:

- Adding time limits to forms and ensure they are submitted with in that time.
- On every interaction with the form, send AJAX request to validate and reactive the form's timelimit.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER can be easily spoofed by the client.

Comment: Okay I get it > one time keys / hashed session variables.. lol

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 provides a new input type . The purpose of the  element is to provide a secure way to authenticate users.The  tag specifies a key-pair generator field in a form.

When the form is submitted, two keys are generated, one private and one public.

The private key is stored locally, and the public key is sent to the server. The public key could be used to generate a client certificate to authenticate the user in the future.

[Keygen tag in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501196/keygen-tag-in-html5)

[RFC](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html#the-keygen-element)