# Html5 <keygen> tag importance

Tags: html, ssl, html5-keygen

I am getting started to know about html5 new elements.

I have some doubts in `<keygen>` tag.

All i can find somewhat i understood, apart from all the documents i read, i have the    following questions will raise.

Is this important for creating every new website?

Where is the exact situation to use `<keygen>`?

If i am not use this, what the issues are i can meet?

Is there relation between keygen and `ssl`?

Can you help me to fix this sir?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keygen tag in HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501196/keygen-tag-in-html5)

Comment: I referred that link @ColinBacon. I can't able to find out for above questions.. Thanks