# what's spkac in crypto module of nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I found `spkac` from this document:
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_certificate_exportchallenge_spkac

> const spkac = getSpkacSomehow();

The docs says `getSpkacSomehow`.

How can I get spkac? What's the detail?

Answer (score 2):

SPKAC represents Netscape signed public key and challenge.

As stated in the doc, in this scenario, the SPKAC should come from an HTML form's [`<keygen>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen).

Though you can also use openssl to generate a SPKAC manually: `openssl spkac -key key.pem -challenge hello -out spkac.cnf`, see [openssl doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-spkac.html)

Anyway, since the `<keygen>` element has been deprecated, this should not be used anymore.

If you're interested, here's a [little history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854215/798042) about SPKAC.